# Transit visa requirement for flights connecting through Gatwick

Tags: canada, india, london

Two of us holding Indian passports are flying from the Middle East to Toronto with British Airways. There is a layover of about 7 hours at Gatwick airport. The flight lands at the North terminal and the flight to Toronto leaves from the South terminal. We are holding valid Canadian visit visas.

Do we need to obtain a separate transit visa for transferring from the North to the south terminal and boarding a connecting flight in Gatwick?

Comment: Since there is no airside connection between the Gatwick terminals, you need to pass through passport control and enter the UK in order to get to your connecting flight. However, it sounds like you'll qualify for the landside Transit-Without-Visa provision.

Answer (score -1):

According to this web page from gov.uk, you do not need a transit visa.
https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no

Exemptions
You don’t need a visa if you have one of the following:

a visa for Canada, New Zealand, Australia or the USA (this can be used for travel to any country)

Comment: This search result is not relevant for the OP, who needs to enter the UK to transfer between terminals at Gatwick. (There is no airside connection between the terminals).